# Can't get entries more recent than date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, monk

i'm pretty new at using mongodb with monk on node, so far i really enjoyed it. but, that was until i was trying to make a query that would return every entries whoses date are more recent than a date i gave in the query:

```
collection.find({date: {$gt: new Date(lastClear)}, {fields: _id:0}, function (e, data) {
    // data is empty, e is null
    console.log(e, data);
});
```

it should return a couple of entries but it doesn't, what did i do wrong ?

edit: i store this kind of entry:

```
{
    _id: 507f1f77bcf86cd799439011,
   postuniqid: 0123456789,
   date: new Date("Fri Jan 23 2015 21:18:51 GMT+0100 (CET)"),
   author: 3,
   message: 'foo'
}
```

finally, lastClear is a date object, as for my tests, it equals to *new Date("Wed Jan 21 2015 23:45:43 GMT+0100 (CET)")*.

Comment: Please update your question with a sample document in your collection to reflect how the date is being stored. The more information you provide, more likely are you to get good answers.

Comment: i added a sample of what kind of data i insert into collection

Comment: @Makaron Can you edit your sample doc to show its actual `date` value and then also include the value of `lastClear` in your query? It's all about the specifics of these values.

Comment: i added these values

Comment: @Makaron You're missing a trailing `}` in your `find` query object, but other than that it worked for me when using those values.  I'm not sure what the `{fields: _id:0}` parameter of your find call is trying to do, however.

Comment: oh yes ! i forget to edit the missing }, the fields modifier is here to exclude a field from the result queries, without it, it doesn't work either

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using Monk, I decided to use the default MongoDB driver. I don't get why but modifiers don't work anymore with Monk on my database or collection. The default driver works like a charm.